# sql select where columns don't contain a number

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need an sql command that would select all rows that don't contain a certain number.

What I have:

```
    Select * from table
    Where (col1 != 1 or col2 != 1 or col3 != 1)
```

The problem is this does not select any rows that have either of the columns empty.
All 3 columns are integer type.

Comment: Tht still doesn't select any of the rows that have at least 1 empty column.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. (When you say empty you mean _null_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is distinct from` instead of `!=` for nullable columns:

```
select * 
from my_table
where (
    col1 is distinct from 1 
    or col2 is distinct from 1 
    or col3 is distinct from 1)
```